# How can I use row values in a DataFrame as the columns for manipulation in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a database in which the first row I have years, and the first column the categories for each series. I would like to know how can I invert that?

```
Unnamed=0          2001 2002 2003

General             456  567  543
Cleaning            234  234  344
```

Is it possible to have a column date and each column with the variable I need?

```
Date       General    Cleaning

2001         456          234
2002         567          234
2003         543          344
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) for transpose, then [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) to new column name and last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.T.rename_axis('Date').reset_index()
print (df)
   Date  General  Cleaning
0  2001      456       234
1  2002      567       234
2  2003      543       344
```

And if need first column as `index`:

```
df = df.T.rename_axis('Date')
print (df)
      General  Cleaning
Date                   
2001      456       234
2002      567       234
2003      543       344
```

---

```
df = df.T.rename_axis(None)
print (df)
      General  Cleaning
2001      456       234
2002      567       234
2003      543       344
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Although after reseting the index I got:

Date        1            2 
0                General  Cleaning
1  2001      456       234
2  2002      567       234
3  2003      543       344

How can I use the row as the categories?

Comment: I think you need second or third solution.

Comment: I tried the three solutions, but in Jupyter Notebook, the categories appear in the second row, below each index number. I would need each category in the first row to maniupulate the values?

Comment: I dont understand. Can you edit question what you get because bad formatting of comments? Thanks.

Comment: Or maybe need first step set first column to index `df= df.set_index('Unnamed=0').T.rename_axis('Date').reset_index()`